# d3: how can I load external CSV file into data?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am trying to learn how to load external data (in my computer) into d3 code.

However, I can't load data just as the tutorial do `d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data)`.

I tried to attach the URL like `d3.csv("users/file/data.csv")` but it didn't work.

Please let me know how to load the CSV file that is located in my computer.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is that your browser needs to be able to access the file using the URL that you provide, so if you host your d3 code on a web server, then you have to host the data.csv as well.

If you use a relative path, then the path is relative to your HTML file.

Try using

```
d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data)]
```

but make sure that data.csv is in the same location as the HTML file that you are using for your HTML.

Comment: Saved my day. I was placing the csv wrt to my java script index.js and not my index.html file. took me hours to figure out